# Get the closest class from a list jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's hard to explain, so I created an example:

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qn26w/19/)

My idea is to change the color of each column when the respective input is in action...

If anyone has a better idea to do this - please let me know!

When I focus the input, I need the current class of the column.

- first column input, get the class of the RED column
- and the second one, get the class of the BLUE column
- and so go's on...

Because if I get the class, then I can manipulate anything with this class.

the code is here:

```
$(".inputTest").focusin(function(){
    var class = $(this).closest('.tableList')
                    .children().children().children('.auxClass')
                    .attr('class')
                    .split(' ')[0];
                alert(class);
});
```

This is the main code, I try alot of stuffs to get, but nothing.

Thanks

Comment: @John Strickler: its in the demo. please check.

Comment: Your mark-up requires some work. The minimum you could do is add classes around so you can find elements without iterating the DOM a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd add an outer table to split the page in a left and a right hand side.  That way, the inputs below the red border and the inputs below the blue border each have their own table.

Then you can search for the first `td` below the closest table:

```
$(".inputTest").focusin(function(){
    var class = $(this).closest('table').find('td:eq(0)').attr('class');
    alert(class);
});
```

[Click for working jsfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/qn26w/35/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".inputTest").focus(function(){
    var class = $(this).closest('table').parent().attr('class');
    alert(class);
});
```

Edit: Oh, i just realised your inputs are not inside your tables, i think you're gonna have a hard time matching them up to the table/column they're under then. You'd need to add a common attribute to identify them by.

Comment: undefined, u can try in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @ric_bfa: Yeah i just saw that mistake, i figured your inputs were in the same table - check my edit

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers your inputs are not actually in the same "columns" as your red/blue bordered tables, but you can make it so they are using the `<col>` element on the main table, then using the index value you can match your inputs to their column

### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/URTmH/)

---

**HTML** - the only addition is the two `<col>` elements at the start

```
<table width="100%" border="1" class='tableList'>
<col span="2" class="left">
<col span="2" class="right">

    <tr>
        <td class="101 auxClass" width="261px" colspan="2" style="border: solid red;">
            <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%" height="70px">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">Something</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="78px">Something 2</td>
                        <td>Total</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td class="102" width="261px" colspan="2" style="border: solid blue;">
            <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%" height="70px">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                       Something 3
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="78px">Something 4</td>
                        <td width="75px">Total 2</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputTest"/></td>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputTest"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputTest"/></td>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputTest"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputTest"/></td>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputTest"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
col.current {background: #eee;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".inputTest").focusin(function(){
    var colidx = $(this).closest('td').index();


     if (colidx == 1) {
          $("col").removeClass('current');
          $("col.left").addClass('current');
     }  else if (colidx == 3) {
          $("col").removeClass('current');   
          $("col.right").addClass('current');
     }

});
```

Your main table is actually 4 columns, and you need to split it into two halfs of two columns each with the input being in the second column of each half

The jQuery is finding the index of the parent `td` of the input - there are four columns in the main table so the index of a `td` will either be 0,1,2 or 3 - and the `input` is either going to be in cell index 1 or cell index 3. When it finds out which one it add a class to the relevant `col` element to which you can add a background highlight..

Note though that the CSS you can apply to a `col` element is limited, see: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html , for the options so it would depend what you want to do

however I think from this you could probably target td index 0 & 1, or td index 2 & 3 if needed